# Codeigniter Binary MLM Show List of Downlines By User

Tags: php, binary, codeigniter-3, mlm

I am working on Binary MLM using Codeigniter 
And I want to show all the list in a Table of user referred by me and the user referred by my downline.

Anyone I can only show the user that is referred by me. I need to get the user referred by my downline as well.

I want to get all my downline and like the pic below:

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BiWb.png)

DATABASE STRUCTURE:

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlhHl.png)

When you look at the db structure pic you will see 'referred_by == the referral' and username is the referred user.

Comment: So this is like a parent / child relationship, right? Show your database schema, and maybe we can help. Show what you've tried so far too.

Comment: ok bro wait i'll add

Comment: @BrianGottier i updated my question and add db structure pic

Comment: Are you trying to generate an HTML type list with ul and li, or maybe just an array, or what?

Comment: im trying to add in on a table

Comment: I posted an answer, and I'm hoping it's what you're looking for. If not let me know and I'll remove the answer.

Comment: @BrianGottier what i need is show all the users under me and my referred user. I need to show em all

Comment: Well, I'm off to bed. It's 1AM here, and I have to get up early in the morning. I think you will figure it out. Just keep trying. Good night.